# Разработка командной строки (CLI)

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм

Программе на вход подается `argv` `argc`, мне нужно обрабатывать команды вида:

`cmd cmd1 [cmd2 arg] [cmd3] [cmd4 arg]...`

Текущая реализация работает только если опции в нужном порядке и заданы все опции, каким образом можно реализовать подобно утилитам в линуксе чтобы опции были опциональны и была возможность вызывать в разном порядке? Буду рад любым ссылкам, статьям, идеям. То что пока что пришло в голову это построить конечный автомат, но мне кажется есть какие то решения фреймворки для такой типовой задачи.

Comment: Может, вам нужен Getopt?

Answer (score 1):

> пришло в голову построить конечный автомат

Этот конечный автомат уже сделан. Называется он *getopt*. Делаем *man 3 getopt* и читаем:

*Функция getopt() разбирает аргументы командной строки. Ее аргументы argc и argv являются счетчиком и массивом аргументов, которые передаются функции main() при запуске программы. Элемент argv, начинающийся с "-" (и не являющийся "-" или "--"), считается опцией. Символы этого элемента (не считая начального "-") являются символами опций. При каждом повторном вызове getopt() возвращаются символы следующей опции.*

Есть более продвинутый вариант этого автомата. Называется *getopt_long()*

Comment: а там есть возможность опции делать без знаков "-"?

Comment: @Ildar без знака "-" или "--" называется не"опция", а "параметр". И, да, их тоже можно обрабатывать в рамках этой функции.